# function to access the elements in js file

Tags: php, node.js

I have file in js created by convert the swf file to html5 it work prefect, I need to make function to access elements in this file that because I need to call it from php file. This is the code and the elements that want to access is.  `this.light_1_ayaa_17.alpha = 0;`  to change it to be  `this.light_1_ayaa_17.alpha = 1;`
Thanks for all

```
(function (cjs, an) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
var lib={};var ss={};var img={};
lib.ssMetadata = [
    {name:"page2_atlas_1", frames: [[1364,654,591,113],[1364,0,595,176],     
[1364,538,594,114],[1364,769,594,112],[1364,178,595,120], 
[1364,422,595,114],[1364,300,595,120],[0,0,1362,1068]]}
];


(lib.AnMovieClip = function(){
this.actionFrames = [];
this.ignorePause = false;
this.gotoAndPlay = function(positionOrLabel){
    cjs.MovieClip.prototype.gotoAndPlay.call(this,positionOrLabel);
}
this.play = function(){
    cjs.MovieClip.prototype.play.call(this);
}
this.gotoAndStop = function(positionOrLabel){
    cjs.MovieClip.prototype.gotoAndStop.call(this,positionOrLabel);
}
this.stop = function(){
    cjs.MovieClip.prototype.stop.call(this);
}
}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
// symbols:



(lib.CachedBmp_27 = function() {
this.initialize(ss["page2_atlas_1"]);
this.gotoAndStop(0);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.CachedBmp_26 = function() {
this.initialize(ss["page2_atlas_1"]);
this.gotoAndStop(1);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.CachedBmp_25 = function() {
this.initialize(ss["page2_atlas_1"]);
this.gotoAndStop(2);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.CachedBmp_24 = function() {
this.initialize(ss["page2_atlas_1"]);
this.gotoAndStop(3);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.CachedBmp_23 = function() {
this.initialize(ss["page2_atlas_1"]);
this.gotoAndStop(4);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.CachedBmp_22 = function() {
this.initialize(ss["page2_atlas_1"]);
this.gotoAndStop(5);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.CachedBmp_21 = function() {
this.initialize(ss["page2_atlas_1"]);
this.gotoAndStop(6);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.CachedBmp_20 = function() {
this.initialize(ss["page2_atlas_1"]);
this.gotoAndStop(7);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();
// helper functions:

function mc_symbol_clone() {
var clone = this._cloneProps(new this.constructor(this.mode, 
this.startPosition, this.loop, this.reversed));
clone.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame);
clone.paused = this.paused;
clone.framerate = this.framerate;
return clone;
}

function getMCSymbolPrototype(symbol, nominalBounds, frameBounds) {
var prototype = cjs.extend(symbol, cjs.MovieClip);
prototype.clone = mc_symbol_clone;
prototype.nominalBounds = nominalBounds;
prototype.frameBounds = frameBounds;
return prototype;
}


(lib.Symbol20 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("AwnEpIAAj7MAn2AAAIAAD7gA3OgtIAAj7MAucAAAIAAD7g");
this.shape.setTransform(148.6875,29.6625);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol20, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.4,59.4), null);


(lib.Symbol19 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("Az/EYIAAj6MArGAAAIAAD6gA3GgdIAAj6IadAAIAAD6g");
this.shape.setTransform(147.825,28.0375);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol19, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,295.7,56.1), null);


(lib.Symbol18 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
 this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("AGuG5IAAj7IQeAAIAAD7gA3NBfIAAj6MAubAAAIAAD6gA3Li9IAAj7MAh2AAAIAAD7g");
this.shape.setTransform(148.6375,44.0625);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol18, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.3,88.2), null);


(lib.Symbol17 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("AOFJGIAAj7IJDAAIAAD7gA3NEbIAAj6MAubAAAIAADsIgGAAIAAAOgA3NgRIAAj7MAubAAAIAAD7gA3HlKIAAj7IO4AAIAAD7g");
this.shape.setTransform(148.6375,58.1625);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol17, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.3,116.4), null);


(lib.Symbol16 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.instance = new lib.CachedBmp_27();
this.instance.setTransform(0,0,0.5,0.5);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol16, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,295.5,56.5), null);


(lib.Symbol15 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("ANzJrIAAj6IJbAAIAAD6gA3NEnIAAj6MAubAAAIAAD6gA3NglIAAj6MAubAAAIAAD6gA3ElwIAAj6IOlAAIAAD6g");
this.shape.setTransform(148.6375,61.9375);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol15, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.3,123.9), null);


(lib.Symbol14 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.instance = new lib.CachedBmp_26();
this.instance.setTransform(0,0,0.5,0.5);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol14, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.5,88), null);


(lib.Symbol13 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("AA2EiIAAj6IWWAAIAAD6gA3LgnIAAj6IDCAAIAAD6g");
this.shape.setTransform(148.3875,28.9875);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol13, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,296.8,58), null);


(lib.Symbol12 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("Az5EYIAAj6MArHAAAIAAD6gA3NgdIAAj6IYyAAIAAD6g");
this.shape.setTransform(148.6125,27.9875);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol12, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.3,56), null);


(lib.Symbol11 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.instance = new lib.CachedBmp_25();
this.instance.setTransform(0,0,0.5,0.5);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol11, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297,57), null);


(lib.Symbol10 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("AA9GoIAAj7IWNAAIAAD7gA3NB/IAAj6MAubAAAIAAD6gA3NisIAAj7IIQAAIAAD7g");
this.shape.setTransform(148.6375,42.3625);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol10, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.3,84.8), null);


(lib.Symbol9 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("ArOG0IAAj7MAibAAAIAAD7gA3MCCIAAiEIABAAIAAh2MAuYAAAIAAD6gA3Li4IAAj7IHhAAIAAD7g");
this.shape.setTransform(148.5,43.5625);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol9, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297,87.2), null);


(lib.Symbol8 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("AxrB9IAAj5MAjXAAAIAAD5g");
this.shape.setTransform(113.2375,12.5125);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol8, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,226.5,25.1), null);


(lib.Symbol7 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("Az5EZIAAj6MArHAAAIAAD6gA3OgeIAAj6ILbAAIAAD6g");
this.shape.setTransform(148.65,28.125);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol7, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.3,56.3), null);


(lib.Symbol6 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.instance = new lib.CachedBmp_24();
this.instance.setTransform(0,0,0.5,0.5);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol6, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297,56), null);


(lib.Symbol5 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.instance = new lib.CachedBmp_23();
this.instance.setTransform(0,0,0.5,0.5);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol5, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.5,60), null);


(lib.Symbol4 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.instance = new lib.CachedBmp_22();
this.instance.setTransform(0,0,0.5,0.5);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol4, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.5,57), null);


(lib.Symbol3 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(102,153,51,0.251)").s().p("ApgEmIAAj6MAgxAAAIAAD6gA3QgrIAAj6MAihAAAIAAD6g");
this.shape.setTransform(148.9,29.4);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol3, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.8,58.8), null);


(lib.Symbol1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.instance = new lib.CachedBmp_21();
this.instance.setTransform(0,0,0.5,0.5);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol1, new 
cjs.Rectangle(0,0,297.5,60), null);


// stage content:
(lib.page2 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
var props = new Object();
props.mode = mode;
props.startPosition = startPosition;
props.labels = {};
props.loop = loop;
props.reversed = reversed;
cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

// Layer_1
this.instance = new lib.CachedBmp_20();
this.instance.setTransform(6.1,12.1,0.5,0.5);

this.light_1_ayaa_17 = new lib.Symbol20();
this.light_1_ayaa_17.name = "light_1_ayaa_17";
this.light_1_ayaa_17.setTransform(172.3,83.35,1,1,0,0,0,148.7,29.7);
this.light_1_ayaa_17.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_24 = new lib.Symbol19();
this.light_1_ayaa_24.name = "light_1_ayaa_24";
this.light_1_ayaa_24.setTransform(171.85,496.6,1,1,0,0,0,147.8,28.1);
this.light_1_ayaa_24.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_23 = new lib.Symbol18();
this.light_1_ayaa_23.name = "light_1_ayaa_23";
this.light_1_ayaa_23.setTransform(171.65,451.8,1,1,0,0,0,148.7,44.1);
this.light_1_ayaa_23.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_22 = new lib.Symbol17();
this.light_1_ayaa_22.name = "light_1_ayaa_22";
this.light_1_ayaa_22.setTransform(172.05,373.95,1,1,0,0,0,148.7,58.1);
this.light_1_ayaa_22.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_21 = new lib.Symbol16();
this.light_1_ayaa_21.name = "light_1_ayaa_21";
this.light_1_ayaa_21.setTransform(172.2,312.1,1,1,0,0,0,147.7,28.3);
this.light_1_ayaa_21.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_20 = new lib.Symbol15();
this.light_1_ayaa_20.name = "light_1_ayaa_20";
this.light_1_ayaa_20.setTransform(171.8,247.75,1,1,0,0,0,148.7,62);
this.light_1_ayaa_20.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_19 = new lib.Symbol14();
this.light_1_ayaa_19.name = "light_1_ayaa_19";
this.light_1_ayaa_19.setTransform(171.9,166.85,1,1,0,0,0,148.8,43.9);
this.light_1_ayaa_19.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_18 = new lib.Symbol13();
this.light_1_ayaa_18.name = "light_1_ayaa_18";
this.light_1_ayaa_18.setTransform(172.5,117.7,1,1,0,0,0,148.4,29);
this.light_1_ayaa_18.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_16 = new lib.Symbol12();
this.light_1_ayaa_16.name = "light_1_ayaa_16";
this.light_1_ayaa_16.setTransform(521.85,495.95,1,1,0,0,0,148.6,28);
this.light_1_ayaa_16.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_15 = new lib.Symbol11();
this.light_1_ayaa_15.name = "light_1_ayaa_15";
this.light_1_ayaa_15.setTransform(522.25,465.95,1,1,0,0,0,148.5,28.6);
this.light_1_ayaa_15.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_14 = new lib.Symbol10();
this.light_1_ayaa_14.name = "light_1_ayaa_14";
this.light_1_ayaa_14.setTransform(522.45,420.65,1,1,0,0,0,148.7,42.4);
this.light_1_ayaa_14.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_13 = new lib.Symbol9();
this.light_1_ayaa_13.name = "light_1_ayaa_13";
this.light_1_ayaa_13.setTransform(522.1,360.2,1,1,0,0,0,148.5,43.6);
this.light_1_ayaa_13.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_12 = new lib.Symbol8();
this.light_1_ayaa_12.name = "light_1_ayaa_12";
this.light_1_ayaa_12.setTransform(557.25,328.55,1,1,0,0,0,113.2,12.5);
this.light_1_ayaa_12.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_11 = new lib.Symbol7();
this.light_1_ayaa_11.name = "light_1_ayaa_11";
this.light_1_ayaa_11.setTransform(522.3,279.5,1,1,0,0,0,148.7,28.1);
this.light_1_ayaa_11.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_10 = new lib.Symbol6();
this.light_1_ayaa_10.name = "light_1_ayaa_10";
this.light_1_ayaa_10.setTransform(522.35,248.6,1,1,0,0,0,148.6,27.9);
this.light_1_ayaa_10.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_9 = new lib.Symbol5();
this.light_1_ayaa_9.name = "light_1_ayaa_9";
this.light_1_ayaa_9.setTransform(521.95,217.2,1,1,0,0,0,148.7,29.9);
this.light_1_ayaa_9.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_8 = new lib.Symbol4();
this.light_1_ayaa_8.name = "light_1_ayaa_8";
this.light_1_ayaa_8.setTransform(521.95,152.45,1,1,0,0,0,148.7,28.6);
this.light_1_ayaa_8.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_7 = new lib.Symbol3();
this.light_1_ayaa_7.name = "light_1_ayaa_7";
this.light_1_ayaa_7.setTransform(522.65,118.05,1,1,0,0,0,148.9,29.4);
this.light_1_ayaa_7.alpha = 0;

this.light_1_ayaa_6 = new lib.Symbol1();
this.light_1_ayaa_6.name = "light_1_ayaa_6";
this.light_1_ayaa_6.setTransform(522.3,83.4,1,1,0,0,0,148.7,29.9);
this.light_1_ayaa_6.alpha = 0;

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.light_1_ayaa_6},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_7},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_8},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_9},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_10},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_11},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_12},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_13},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_14},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_15},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_16},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_18},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_19},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_20},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_21},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_22},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_23},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_24},{t:this.light_1_ayaa_17},{t:this.instance}]}).wait(1));

this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = p = new lib.AnMovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(356.1,287.1,331,259);
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
id: '78CEDDBFFD0B4FCDA1C52CBD0258F734',
width: 700,
height: 550,
fps: 24,
color: "#FFFFFF",
opacity: 1.00,
manifest: [
    {src:"images/page2_atlas_1.png?1634392677498", id:"page2_atlas_1"}
],
preloads: []
};



// bootstrap callback support:

(lib.Stage = function(canvas) {
createjs.Stage.call(this, canvas);
}).prototype = p = new createjs.Stage();

p.setAutoPlay = function(autoPlay) {
this.tickEnabled = autoPlay;
}
p.play = function() { this.tickEnabled = true; 
this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndPlay(this.getTimelinePosition()) }
p.stop = function(ms) { if(ms) this.seek(ms); this.tickEnabled = false; }
p.seek = function(ms) { this.tickEnabled = true; 
this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndStop(lib.properties.fps * ms / 1000); }
p.getDuration = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).totalFrames / 
lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

p.getTimelinePosition = function() { return 
this.getChildAt(0).currentFrame / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

an.bootcompsLoaded = an.bootcompsLoaded || [];
if(!an.bootstrapListeners) {
an.bootstrapListeners=[];
}

an.bootstrapCallback=function(fnCallback) {
an.bootstrapListeners.push(fnCallback);
if(an.bootcompsLoaded.length > 0) {
    for(var i=0; i<an.bootcompsLoaded.length; ++i) {
        fnCallback(an.bootcompsLoaded[i]);
    }
}
};

an.compositions = an.compositions || {};
an.compositions['78CEDDBFFD0B4FCDA1C52CBD0258F734'] = {
getStage: function() { return exportRoot.stage; },
getLibrary: function() { return lib; },
getSpriteSheet: function() { return ss; },
getImages: function() { return img; }
};

an.compositionLoaded = function(id) {
an.bootcompsLoaded.push(id);
for(var j=0; j<an.bootstrapListeners.length; j++) {
    an.bootstrapListeners[j](id);
}
}

an.getComposition = function(id) {
return an.compositions[id];
}


an.makeResponsive = function(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType, 
domContainers) {        
var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;      
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);        
resizeCanvas();     
function resizeCanvas() {           
    var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;            
    var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;          
    var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, 
sRatio=1;           
    if(isResp) {                
        if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || 
(respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
            sRatio = lastS;                
        }               
        else if(!isScale) {                 
            if(iw<w || ih<h)                        
                sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
        }               
        else if(scaleType==1) {                 
            sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
        }               
        else if(scaleType==2) {                 
            sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);              
        }           
    }
    domContainers[0].width = w * pRatio * sRatio;           
    domContainers[0].height = h * pRatio * sRatio;
    domContainers.forEach(function(container) {             
        container.style.width = w * sRatio + 'px';              
        container.style.height = h * sRatio + 'px';         
    });
    stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;           
    stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;
    lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;            
    stage.tickOnUpdate = false;            
    stage.update();            
    stage.tickOnUpdate = true;      
}
}
an.handleSoundStreamOnTick = function(event) {
if(!event.paused){
    var stageChild = stage.getChildAt(0);
    if(!stageChild.paused || stageChild.ignorePause){
        stageChild.syncStreamSounds();
    }
}
}


})(createjs = createjs||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{});
var createjs, AdobeAn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this

```
<?php
$path = 'the/path/of/your/file';
$content = file_get_contents($path);
$modifiedContent = str_replace('this.light_1_ayaa_17.alpha = 0;', 'this.light_1_ayaa_17.alpha = 1;', $content);
file_put_contents($file, $modifiedContent);
```

Comment: need function to control the element of this attribute, not to replace text in the file, it will work on run time of the page to control which is will be on and which not

Answer (score 0):

**You definitely can't do this from PHP, as this content is 100% generate on the client-side.**

This is Adobe Animate output, which is basically a library of symbols (exported on `lib.x`).

There should also be HTML output (not shown in the post), which boostraps everything, and is like your main application. It is usually an `exportRoot`. In order to change properties, you need to find the element in the instantiated display list.

It looks like `this.light_1_ayaa_17` is instantiated using a Timeline in `page2`, which I don't see used elsewhere. I suspect it becomes your exportRoot in the HTML (`exportRoot = new page2()` or something). Therefore, you should be able to use:

```js
exportRoot.light_1_ayaa_17.alpha = 1
```

However, because it is in a Timeline, you would have to wait for it to finish updating, or the property may be reset.

This answer may not work for you, since I can not see what the HTML content is, and the Timeline it is part of is fairly complicated. But this should give you an idea on how you usually can directly update Animate content.

Best of luck!